# How to catch the memory leakage of a process in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, memory, memory-leaks

I am working on an embedded Linux system (kernel-5.24.0), where is 128MB RAM in it.

Now I found a process has memory leakage (from the `free` and `available` output of `free -k`), and I am trying to figure out where is the leakage from.

So I used the famous `valgrind --leak-check=yes --tool=memcheck myapp`, and I got following summary after running it for 9 hours,

```
==6573== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6573==     in use at exit: 34,793,251 bytes in 317,231 blocks
==6573==   total heap usage: 50,635,131 allocs, 50,317,900 frees, 2,733,852,406 bytes allocated
....
==6573== LEAK SUMMARY:
==6573==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==6573==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6573==      possibly lost: 318,088 bytes in 5,321 blocks
==6573==    still reachable: 34,475,131 bytes in 311,908 blocks
==6573==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6573== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==6573== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==6573==
==6573== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==6573== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==6573== ERROR SUMMARY: 1893697 errors from 477 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

It reported `possibly lost: 318,088 bytes`, but with `free -k` I found the `free` and `Available` are descreasing (the decreased count is more than 318,088 bytes), so I am confused.

With `pmap -x pidof myapp` I found the process's `PSS` and `Dirty` of `[heap]` are increased slowly (by Kilo bytes).

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx 294
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         117128       41792       49996        7956       25340       64772
Swap:             0           0           0

1307: myapp
Address           Kbytes     PSS   Dirty    Swap  Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000       4       4       0       0  r-xp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000410000       4       4       4       0  rwxp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000c06000    5060    5012    5012       0  rwxp  [heap]
000000007009f000    2208    2208    2208       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
00000000703ad000     936     936     936       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070497000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]
0000000070498000    8192       8       8       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070c98000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx 295
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         117128       41848       49940        7956       25340       64716
Swap:             0           0           0

1307: myapp
Address           Kbytes     PSS   Dirty    Swap  Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000       4       4       0       0  r-xp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000410000       4       4       4       0  rwxp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000c06000    5060    5012    5012       0  rwxp  [heap]
000000007009f000    2208    2208    2208       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
00000000703ad000     936     936     936       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070497000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]
0000000070498000    8192       8       8       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070c98000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]
........
........

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx 583
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         117128       41940       49848        7956       25340       64624
Swap:             0           0           0

1307: myapp
Address           Kbytes     PSS   Dirty    Swap  Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000       4       4       0       0  r-xp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000410000       4       4       4       0  rwxp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000c06000    5192    5092    5092       0  rwxp  [heap]
000000007009f000    2208    2208    2208       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
00000000703ad000     936     936     936       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070497000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]
0000000070498000    8192       8       8       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070c98000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx 584
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         117128       41896       49892        7956       25340       64668
Swap:             0           0           0

1307: myapp
Address           Kbytes     PSS   Dirty    Swap  Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000       4       4       0       0  r-xp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000410000       4       4       4       0  rwxp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000c06000    5192    5092    5092       0  rwxp  [heap]
000000007009f000    2208    2208    2208       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
00000000703ad000     936     936     936       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070497000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]
0000000070498000    8192       8       8       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070c98000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]

......
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx 759
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         117128       42028       49760        7956       25340       64536
Swap:             0           0           0

1307: myapp
Address           Kbytes     PSS   Dirty    Swap  Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000       4       4       0       0  r-xp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000410000       4       4       4       0  rwxp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000c06000    5192    5092    5092       0  rwxp  [heap]
000000007009f000    2208    2208    2208       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
00000000703ad000     936     936     936       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070497000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]
0000000070498000    8192       8       8       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070c98000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx 760
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         117128       41864       49924        7956       25340       64700
Swap:             0           0           0

1307: myapp
Address           Kbytes     PSS   Dirty    Swap  Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000       4       4       0       0  r-xp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000410000       4       4       4       0  rwxp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000c06000    5192    5092    5092       0  rwxp  [heap]
000000007009f000    2208    2208    2208       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
00000000703ad000     936     936     936       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070497000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]
0000000070498000    8192       8       8       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070c98000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]

.......
.......
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx 1000
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         117128       41756       50032        7956       25340       64804
Swap:             0           0           0

1307: myapp
Address           Kbytes     PSS   Dirty    Swap  Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000       4       4       0       0  r-xp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000410000       4       4       4       0  rwxp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000c06000    5192    5092    5092       0  rwxp  [heap]
000000007009f000    2208    2208    2208       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
00000000703ad000     936     936     936       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070497000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]
0000000070498000    8192       8       8       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070c98000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx 1001
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         117128       41896       49892        7956       25340       64664
Swap:             0           0           0

1307: myapp
Address           Kbytes     PSS   Dirty    Swap  Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000       4       4       0       0  r-xp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000410000       4       4       4       0  rwxp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000c06000    5192    5116    5116       0  rwxp  [heap]
000000007009f000    2208    2208    2208       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
00000000703ad000     936     936     936       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070497000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]
0000000070498000    8192       8       8       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070c98000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx 1002
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         117128       41796       49992        7956       25340       64764
Swap:             0           0           0

1307: myapp
Address           Kbytes     PSS   Dirty    Swap  Mode  Mapping
0000000000400000       4       4       0       0  r-xp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000410000       4       4       4       0  rwxp  /usr/bin/myapp
0000000000c06000    5192    5116    5116       0  rwxp  [heap]
000000007009f000    2208    2208    2208       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
00000000703ad000     936     936     936       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070497000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]
0000000070498000    8192       8       8       0  rwxp    [ anon ]
0000000070c98000       4       0       0       0  ---p    [ anon ]
```

Is the report of valgrind correct in my case, is the `possibly lost` meaningful and worth fixing? The memory usage of `myapp` process is increasing in trend (the number is up and down with several Kilo bytes, but the trend is increasing), so is there any other way (or tool in valgrind) to help identifying the memory leakage?

And from the output pattern of `pmap`, the `PSS` and `Dirty` are increased slowly, is there way (user space tool or kernel feature) to help tracking where is the memory request from `myapp`?